# How to synchronize some part of the method in an ejb

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, synchronization, ejb, jboss6.x

I have a stateless ejb which is deployed in jboss application server and I had to synchronize some part of the code.

I used

```
synchronized(this) {
....
}
```

Later I realized that the code will fail because the container creates an ejb pool and my code will not work as expected.

So I came with an idea to create a static final object and pass the reference to the synchronized block. Below is the code snippet.

```
private static final Object object = new Object();

synchronized(object) {
.....
}
```

I want to know how far is the code correct?

Comment: Nobody can really answer your question about correctness without knowing the requirement. Synchronizing on one single ojbect (like you did) makes sure that only one thread is able to execute that synchronized block. If that is what you wanted, then it is correct. But I highly doubt that this is what you really need.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes, I just want to know using a static final object grants access to the block for only one thread or not. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to sinchronize a stateless EJB in a ejb-pool under JBoss you have to use a SingletonEJB in which you can use syncronized block.

With EJB3.1 you can use @Singleton annotation:

```
@Singleton

@Remote
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding = "SingletonBean")
@Startup

public class SingletonBean { ....}
```

Altough, with EJB3 you had to configure by yourself Jboss in order to have a Singleton EJB.

See : [Implement an HA Singleton](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Implement_an_HA_Singleton.html)